# How to select the first character on a string in python then use that first character in an if statement

Tags: python

```
def are_you_playing_banjo(name):
    first_char = name[0]
    if first_char != "r" or "R":
        outcome = name + " does not play banjo"
    else:
        outcome = name + " plays banjo"
    return outcome

p = are_you_playing_banjo("rick")
print (p)
```

**This should print "{name} plays banjo" because the name starts with "r" and I suspect that there is something wrong with how I selected the first character of the string and used it in an if statement. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a string method `startswith()` which will do what you need.

Replace

```py
first_char = name[0]
if first_char.....
```

With a single if statement

```py
if not name.lower().startswith("r"):
```

Answer (score 1):

This if statement

```
if first_char != "r" or "R":
```

should be

```
if first_char.lower() != "r":
```

or

```
if first_char not in "rR":
```

since the first statement essentially evaluates to

```
if (first_char != "r") or ("R"):
```

which will always be `True` since `"R"` is truthy since it is a non-empty string.